# Raspberry pi boot partition cannot be accessed after change in boot folder

Tags: raspberry-pi, config, boot, raspbian, delete-file

I am trying to boot my raspberry pi and the first light is green, the second red and the other ones are not on.
It was working fine until I unplugged the SD Card from the pi and plugged it in windows, then i deleted the config.txt file.

I tried to put SD card in the pi again but it just doesn't boot, noting happens except the two lights I talked about.
I took another raspberry pi and another SD card and installed a raspbian image (like on the first one). Everything is working on this second SD card and raspberry pi so I copied the boot folder from this one into the boot folder of the other one.

Now both of them are not working !!!!! I would like to get the first pi to boot without re-installing everything because a lot of stuff was configured, do you have any ideas ?

Maybe re-installing the image on the first pi but before that saving the entire pi folder, then after re-installing copying it back would work ?

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution, Windows sucks a LOT less today in my mind. Thanks to chkdsk I restored the first config.txt file, fsck didn't manage. So to everyone doing some stupid deletion like me, you got windows having your back with chkdsk.

To go back in time : open a command prompt (cmd) then type : chkdsk /F.

If your file system is F of course.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

Why did you delete the config.txt file?
It's important, put it back, and try booting again.
Here's a copy of my raspian config.txt

```
# For more options and information see 
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=16
#hdmi_mode=9

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

sdtv_aspect=3

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
arm_freq=700

core_freq=250
sdram_freq=400
over_voltage=0

gpu_mem=64
```

Comment: It probably wasn't very smart yes. The problem is that I can't put it back, well not the exact same one at least, I didn't save it before doing so. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Come on, I need your help. Oh and no need to tell me to undelete the file with a recover for example because I already tried and it did not work.

Comment: best bet is to download the image again, and mount it as a loopback device and mount it and take a look at the config.txt on the original image.

Comment: Thank you very much stu, As I answered I found the solution to my problem, Thank you for your time.